# Results missing from ANCOMBC2 in R

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm doing a differential abundance analysis

I try to follow this ANCOMBC2 tutorial :https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ANCOMBC/inst/doc/ANCOMBC2.html

It seems like there is no colomns starting with "passed_ss_" in the output$res_pair

Do you have any other ressource than this tutorial ?